# stop form submitting in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, forms

I am catching the form submission with jquery.

This submit handler works in all browsers except internet explorer where it just does the submit.

How can I fix it?

```
$('#editForm').live('submit', function() {
        var data = [];
        var finalForm = $(this).serializeArray();
        var differences = 0;
        for (var i in initialForm) {
            if (!objectsAreSame(initialForm[i], finalForm[i])) {
                data[differences] = finalForm[i];
                differences++;
            }
        }
        console.log('diff: ', differences);
        if (differences > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: site_url + 'ajax/contact',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: finalForm[0].value,
                    method: 'editContact',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#contact' + finalForm[0].value).hide("drop", {direction: 'up'}, 500, function() {
                        $('#contact' + finalForm[0].value).replaceWith(data);
                        $('#contact' + finalForm[0].value).show("drop", {direction: 'up'}, 500, function() {
                            $(document).trigger('close.facebox');
                        });
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

---

looks like its not even wiring up the submit handler...
doing a straight off return false does nothing...

Comment: Any reason you're using `live`? I suspect that's the problem. If you don't need it, replace it with a normal bind.

Comment: Are there any script errors in IE?  I ran into some issues where IE is a bit more picky with syntax than other browsers which causes the script to never run and the form to behave normally.

Comment: I am using live because the form is generated dynamically when you click the edit button next to a contact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code is not neat enough to read; read this [I4 ways to better jQuery coding](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/14-helpful-jquery-tricks-notes-and-best-practices/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+nettuts+%28NETTUTS%29&utm_content=FeedBurner)

**Anyway below are some hints**

- Remove `console.log()` statements
- Check where the `return` statement location
- Use the IE debugger to catch the value(difference)
- Use `if(..){ }else{ }` statement instead of `if(...){ }` alone

And finally, I think it should be written this way; check where the first return statement is

```js
$('#editForm').live('submit', function() {
    var data = [];
    var finalForm = $(this).serializeArray();
    var differences = 0;
    for (var i in initialForm) {
        if (!objectsAreSame(initialForm[i], finalForm[i])) {
            data[differences] = finalForm[i];
            differences++;
        }
    }
    console.log('diff: ', differences);
    if (differences > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: site_url + 'ajax/contact',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: finalForm[0].value,
                method: 'editContact',
                data: JSON.stringify(data)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#contact' + finalForm[0].value).hide("drop", {direction: 'up'}, 500, function() {
                    $('#contact' + finalForm[0].value).replaceWith(data);
                    $('#contact' + finalForm[0].value).show("drop", {direction: 'up'}, 500, function() {
                        $(document).trigger('close.facebox');
                    });
                });                   
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove all `console.log()` calls from your code. This will cause an error in IE and `return false` won't be called.

Comment: +1 Good point, if you really want to keep in your console messages (should really only be there for development normally) but test with IE use: if(window.console)console.log(data); for example.

Comment: using ie 8, if you press f12 it brings up the dev tools which has console 8D

Comment: Make sure that IE isn't using a cached version of your script. Also test that IE doesn't report a javascript error.

Comment: Cleared the cache, and unless I am missing something there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your function: test if in IE, then return false. Also test if [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) can be called, and call it if its there. Also change your function call to `$('#editForm').live('submit', function(e)` to pass the event to the function:

```
// For IE:
if ($.browser.msie) e.returnValue = false;
// Otherwise: 
if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: this defeats the purpose of using jQuery, which already irons out the differences between browsers.